# What is the running time of this for-loop?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Take `N=5` as one example. The number of operations in the two loops is `5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15`. Which seems to be `N + N-1 + N-2 + N-3 + ... + 1`. Can I say this is `N^2`?

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
     for(int j=i; j<N; j++){
         ...//
     }
}
```

Comment: It reaches N^2 assymptotically!

Comment: This simplifies to `(N(N+1)) / 2`, which is `O(N²)`.

Comment: Is there a worse and best case for this?

Comment: Not with what you are showing here, maybe if you break out early or something. Otherwise it will always run the same number of times for the same N.

Comment: "Is there a worse and best case for this?": no. For fixed `N` the number of iterations is always the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned the complexity of this is (most likely) `O(N2)`, but only if the complexity *in* the loop is `O(1)`. If not, the overall complexity could be different.

Also there could be a worst case, if there is a break-condition in the loop.

Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j = i; j < N; j++){
        if(N % 2 == 1)
            break;
    }
}
```

The best case is `Θ(N)` (all odd N), the worst case is `Θ(N2)` (for all even `N`).
If `N = 2n + 1` (for any positive integer `n`, i.e. `N` is odd), the condition `N % 2 == 1` will be true. So the inner loop will be exited after the first run. So the complexity is `O(N ⋅ 1) = O(N)`.
If `N = 2⋅n` (for any positive integer `n`, i.e. `N` is even), the condition is never true, so the inner loop is completely executed. So the complexity is

```
O(N + N-1 + ... + 2 + 1) = O(N⋅(N+1)/2) = O(N²).
```

If the code in the inner loop needs more than `O(1)`, the overall complexity will not fit into `O(N²)`.

Comment: Since big-O is an upper bound, this is still O(N^2). It may or may not be Theta(N^2).

Comment: You are right. I'll correct this.

Comment: What do you mean by all Odd N and all even N? And why there are best and worst cases?

Comment: I added the explanation to the answer

Answer (score 1):

It is `N(N+1)/2` which in Big-O notation still increases as `N^2` but fairly good as `N^2` goes.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma notation, you obtain this:

[image]